# JS How to control an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

**Scenario:**

I have a function that I want to automatically invoke. But on a mouse click I want this function to stop. How to control an anonymous function in JS?

Example

**HTML**

```
<div id="seventyfive" style="position:absolute; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png" style="width:50px"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').animate(
        {
            'font-size': (back) ? '10px' : '15px',
            opacity: (back) ? 0.3 : 1
        }, 600, function(){pulse(!back)});
    $('#seventyfive img').animate(
        {
            'width': (back) ? '50px' : '40px'
        }, 600);
})(false);

var on = true;
$("#seventyfive").click(function(){

    on = !on;

    if(on){

       // Start/Stop Pulse function
    }

});
```

JSFiddle Example [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ed31hbzg/)

Comment: One thing that jumps to mind is to switch to using CSS animations, making  controlling the animation trivial.  Would you be interested in an answer like that?

Comment: If you want some function to call later why would you make it anonymous at first place?

Comment: You can't really "stop the function", but you can stop the animation: https://api.jquery.com/stop/ . Though I'm not sure if this will still call the callback or not.

Comment: @Scott sure if you have something that would cleanly imitate this

Comment: @FelixKling whats a better alternative? While(true) ... jquery.animate then click on false?

Comment: @stackoverflow: JavaScript is single threaded. `while(true)` is an infinite loop. No other code can run while this loop is executed.

Comment: second the suggestion for manipulating classnames instead of animation logic, much easier.

Comment: @Daniel_L could you demonstrate this? I'm not a huge front end developer

Comment: @stackoverflow https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from hardware acceleration by using CSS, which massively improves performance.

```js
$("#seventyfive").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("pulsing");
});
```

```css
.heart.pulsing img {
  animation: pulse 600ms ease infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="seventyfive" class="heart" style="position:absolute; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png" style="width:50px" />
</div>
```

With this, just apply the `pulsing` class to `#seventyfive`, and the heart will pulse.  Notice that this animates `opacity` and `transform`, not `font-size`, to avoid triggering the browser to perform a re-layout.

Comment: How do I keep the @keyframes css inside of the pulsing class only though?

Comment: Not really possible, [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) is seen as a regular rule like `@font-face` (in this case, you're defining an animation routine).  If you're concerned about collisions, you can always change the name to something more "scoped" like `heart-pulse-animation`.